# java minimal memory usage for output

Tags: java, output

I am trying to solve a problem but getting memory limit 
i think that it is a cause of buffering before output 
i have integers, how can i output them with minimal memory usage ? 
now i am using PrintWriter. is there any other better way ?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class stack_ {
public char index;
public int value;

public stack_(char ind, int val) {
    index = ind;
    value = val;
}
}

public class timous {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    StreamTokenizer in = new StreamTokenizer( new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in)) );
    Vector<stack_> numbers = new Vector<stack_>();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

    in.nextToken();
    char num = (char)in.nval;
    for (char i = 0, k; i<num; i++) {
        in.nextToken();
        if (in.sval.equals("POP")) {
            k = (char)(numbers.size()-1);
            in.nextToken();
            while (numbers.elementAt(k).index!=(char) in.nval)
                k--;
            out.println(numbers.elementAt(k).value);
            numbers.removeElementAt(k);
        }               
        else {
            in.nextToken();
            k = (char)in.nval;
            in.nextToken();
            numbers.add(new stack_(k, (int) in.nval));
        }
    }
    out.flush();
}
}
```

Memory limit test 3; time 0.078; memory 834 KB

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class timous {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StreamTokenizer in = new StreamTokenizer( new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in)) );
        int[] numbers_int = new int[20000];
        char[] numbers_char = new char[20000];
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);

        in.nextToken();
        char num = (char)in.nval;
        for (char i = 0, k, cur=0; i<num; i++) {
            in.nextToken();
            if (in.sval.charAt(1)=='O') {
                k = cur;
                k--;
                in.nextToken();
                while (numbers_char[k]!=(char) in.nval)
                    k--;
                out.println(numbers_int[k]);
                for (; k<19999; k++){
                    numbers_int[k] = numbers_int[k+1];
                    numbers_char[k] = numbers_char[k+1];
                }
                cur--;
            }               
            else {
                in.nextToken();
                numbers_char[cur] = (char)in.nval;
                in.nextToken();
                numbers_int[cur] = (int)in.nval;
                cur++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? what does the code do? Can you give a bit more context? If you require low memory footprint, you've picked the wrong language.

Comment: [problem 1220](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1220)

Comment: After reading the heading it's obvious that you've picked the wrong language `Memory Limit: 0.75 MB`. You need to build this in something that doesn't use a VM to run.

Comment: watch to this solutions ! [accepted solutions](http://acm.timus.ru/rating.aspx?space=1&num=1220&lang=java&count=100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer is a fixed size when you create it.  This means it doesn't matter how you use it or fill it, it won't use more memory.  The default if 8 KB and this is unlikely to be the cause you running out of memory.

It is far more likely to be the Vector (a curious choice for a collection) of stack object, though you would have to create millions of these to cause a problem

BTW Java 7 won't start without a heap of at least 1.1 MB (which is a small part of the program for this size). i.e. you can't even get to print it's version.

```
$ java -mx1000k -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Too small initial heap for new size specified

$ java -mx1100k -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

If you are wonder why Java "needs so much memory", I would say it's nothing these days for most system which run Java. You can buy 32 GB for $200 so 1 MB is worth only 0.6 cents and is re-usable.

---

Given it does really relate to the problem you can parse and otuput int values useing these methods.

```
static int readInt() throws IOException {
    int num = 0, ch;
    while ((ch = System.in.read()) > 0)
        if (ch > ' ')
            break;
    if (ch < 0)
        return -1;
    do {
        num = num * 10 + ch - '0';
        ch = System.in.read();
    } while (ch > ' ');
    return num;
}

static void writeInt(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        System.out.write('0');
        System.out.write('\n');
        return;
    } else if (i < 0) {
        System.out.write('-');
        writeInt(-i);
        return;
    }
    int tens = 1000000000;
    for (; tens > i; tens /= 10) ;
    for (; tens > 0; tens /= 10)
        System.out.write((char) ('0' + i / tens % 10));
    System.out.write('\n');
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    int count = readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int pushPop = readInt();
        switch (pushPop) {
            case -1: // OEF
                return;
            case 36074: // PUSH
            case 71626: // push
                push(readInt(), readInt());
                break;

            case 3542: // PUSH
            case 7094: // pop
                writeInt(pop(readInt()));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that there are a lot of problems with java and his memory usage but this problem is solved using java! it means that there is solution for it ! 
[examples of accepted timing and memory](http://acm.timus.ru/rating.aspx?space=1&num=1220&lang=java&count=100)

Comment: I don't see it as a problem.  The memory usage is rather suspect IMHO as you really just need to trick Java into saying it used less memory as the totals will never be that low.

Comment: and also why i think that problem is connected with output
if i am not mistaken out.print calls toString function for integer and then prints it and i do believe that for this it uses memory !

Comment: I have tried a few thing and I can tell you a) you cannot create any garbage or use the built in functions to parse or output the numbers. b) you need to allocate your stack using blocks of `int[]` which you have to recycle. Arrays of 32-64 appear to be best.  Even with this I get memory usage exceeded on the 3rd test. Note: Hello world says it uses 326 KB. If you just GC it says you used 4885 KB :P

Comment: my code is getting Memory limit exceeded:3, Time:0.125, Mem:894 KB :)

Comment: In that case try maintaining two arrays of `char[]` and `int[]` instead of a Vector of objects are this will use less memory.

Comment: :) i have tried it uses more memory since i am allocating array of 50000 stack_-s

Comment: I got to use less memory, but it gets a Time Limit Reached. ;)

Comment: See how you go. It doesn't pass all the tests anyway.

Comment: i want to know how you reduced memory usage it doesn't meter if it passes tests of not

Comment: Like I said, create two arrays `short[] stackId = new short[20000]; int[] values = new int[20000];` The tests appear to fit into arrays of this size.

Comment: i have shared my code. it is like you have said with arrays but it is not passing test 3. how to do better ?

Comment: Don't use String, or the builtin libraries for parsing or printing the numbers. You have to rewrite those yourself not to use objects. Added code for how I did this.

Comment: it was wrong version i corrected it with int it is similar ! what means parsing or printing ? what to use ?

Comment: give me some time to digest it. it is new for me ! thank you !

Comment: I was thinking about this solution problem with time limit appears because every token is read separately for it there are a lot of calls which i think are time consuming. like scanner and bufferedReader. and also there is no need for chacking for '-' since all numbers are >= 0